# Is there a way to flip the "n" menu with python besides using operators?

Tags: python, add-on

I like having the 3d viewport "n" menu on the left side of my workspace and the toolbar on the right, and I'm wondering if I could build it into an addon, using Context instead of an Operator, maybe even for all windows.

This is the command you can use, with your mouse hovering over the menu:

bpy.ops.screen.region_flip()

or if you press f3, this is what shows:
screen.region_flip > Flip Region

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Would saving your startup file with this change accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jeff. No unfortunately not, I want to build it into an add-on, so people new to Blender can just press a button and have it flipped.